# Should this question on the OSF system be reopened?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

There is a closed question on the OSF system: [Is there a way to move a preprint from one service to another within the OSF system?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109866/is-there-a-way-to-move-a-preprint-from-one-service-to-another-within-the-osf-sys) that has spawned a number of comments as well as two meta questions:

1. [Are questions asking technical issues on academic services on-topic?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4162/are-questions-asking-technical-issues-on-academic-services-on-topic)
2. [Is there a consensus if there is only indirect evidence?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/is-there-a-consensus-if-there-is-only-indirect-evidence)

Both meta questions are quite general and I am not able to understand how to interpret the votes in regards to reopening the original question.

I am not sure another meta questions (i.e., this one) is really needed since there does not seem to be conflicting votes: it is not as if the question has been closed and then reopened and then closed again.

I guess I am asking because I would like to bring closure (even if that means reopening the question) to the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't people just use reopen votes on the question to reopen it, if they think it should be reopened?

Comment: @ff524 I think, if people upvote on (1) but don't vote to reopen it, then there must be some conflicts that make them not doing so?

Comment: In case the number of votes on the yes answer doesn't outnumber the no answer, then we will have a consensus problem here ;)

Comment: @Ooker I voted to re-open before. That vote expired. I voted to re-open again and upvoted the yes answer. This is the best I can do. Let's see what's going to happen.

Comment: @scaaahu thanks. As I'm its OP, I won't vote (or didn't vote) on any answers on these meta questions to avoid bias

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this question is a good fit for our community and should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

No, this question is not a good fit for our community and should be left closed.