# Technical support: rational vs emotion

Tags: discussion, scope

<sub>(Just to be clear, although all of the link here are about my question, I no longer have interest in the original question and only want to generalize the problem.)</sub>

According to [Are questions asking technical issues on academic services on-topic?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4162/14341), I see that:

- The yes answer has 10 votes
- The no answer has -8 votes

Since the polarization is clear cut, I conclude that **rationally we accept technical questions.**

I also see that:

- The specific meta question for the specific question in the main site [Should this question on the OSF system be reopened?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/14341) has a consensus that it should be opened (5 vs 0)
- The question itself ([Is there a way to move a preprint from one service to another within the OSF system?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/109866/14341)) is still closed

According to [What does consensus mean if there is no action?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4222/14341), it seems to me that having consensus doesn't mean it can generate enough support to turn words to actions. The community is still indifferent on its closed status, and based on the votes on that question we can conclude that the community don't think consensus must lead to an accompanying behavior. Therefore, I conclude that generally **emotionally we don't want technical questions.**

I would also speculate that **the reputation of the software/service determines the emotion we have on it.**

What do you think? Is this the perfect example on whether a topic is in borderline, and should be consider case by case? Or can we draw a thinner, finer line?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with technical questions is how "deep in the weeds" the technical issue is. The more specialized the issue or less well-known the platform, the less traction it's going to get here. A question about Web of Science or Google Scholar is much more likely to get answers than a question about the OSF and its related platforms. I suspect that's what happened here, rather than a complete rejection of technical questions.

Comment: So do you think we should leave them all opened and don't close any of them? Whether a question gets answers or not depends on its popularity